# Tkinter Scrolling Issues

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to put a scrollbar on my listbox but because the items I am inserting are so long, but the scrollbar does not scroll all the way. If you run the code below, you will see what I am talking about and notice that the horizontal scroll bar can not scroll all the way to the right. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Same problem occurs for the vertical scroll bar when you add a few more entries.

```
import tkinter

lista=[11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222,
       33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333334444444444444444444467,4444444444444444,
       5555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555556]
master = tkinter.Tk()
master.geometry("400x250")
frame = tkinter.Frame(master, borderwidth=1, highlightthickness=1,
                                                  highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black")
frame.place(bordermode=tkinter.INSIDE, height=240, width=300, y=0, x=30)
LIST = tkinter.Listbox(frame)
LIST.place(bordermode=tkinter.INSIDE, height=237, width=296)

Scroll_Bar_x = tkinter.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL)
Scroll_Bar_x.config(command=LIST.xview)
Scroll_Bar_x.pack(fill=tkinter.X, side=tkinter.BOTTOM)
LIST.config(xscrollcommand=Scroll_Bar_x.set)
Scroll_Bar_y = tkinter.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tkinter.VERTICAL)
Scroll_Bar_y.config(command=LIST.yview)
Scroll_Bar_y.pack(fill=tkinter.Y, side=tkinter.RIGHT)
LIST.config(yscrollcommand=Scroll_Bar_y.set)
for x in lista:
    LIST.insert(0, x)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your scrollbars are overlapping the text in the listbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having issues with overlapping your scroll bars on the placed listbox. Most of the time `place()` is not what you want to use.

Instead try `grid()` this will help keep everything in order and sized correctly.

```
import tkinter

lista=[11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111,22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222,
       33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333334444444444444444444467,4444444444444444,
       5555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555556]
master = tkinter.Tk()
master.geometry("400x250")
frame = tkinter.Frame(master, height=240, width=300, borderwidth=1, highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground="black", highlightcolor="black")
frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
LIST = tkinter.Listbox(frame)
LIST.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
frame.grid_propagate(False)

Scroll_Bar_x = tkinter.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tkinter.HORIZONTAL)
Scroll_Bar_x.config(command=LIST.xview)
Scroll_Bar_x.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
LIST.config(xscrollcommand=Scroll_Bar_x.set)
Scroll_Bar_y = tkinter.Scrollbar(frame, orient=tkinter.VERTICAL)
Scroll_Bar_y.config(command=LIST.yview)
Scroll_Bar_y.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
LIST.config(yscrollcommand=Scroll_Bar_y.set)
for x in lista:
    LIST.insert(0, x)

master.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]